# Не могу выложить Django приложение на Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django

```
DisallowedHost at /

Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'hatsunami.pythonanywhere.com'. You may need to add 'hatsunami.pythonanywhere.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Request Method: GET

Request URL:    http://hatsunami.pythonanywhere.com/

Django Version: 1.10.3

Exception Type: DisallowedHost

Exception Value:    

Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'hatsunami.pythonanywhere.com'. You may need to add 'hatsunami.pythonanywhere.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Exception Location: /home/hatsunami/my-first-blog/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/http/request.py in get_host, line 113

Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi

Python Version: 3.4.3

Python Path:    
['/var/www',
 '.',
 '',
 '/var/www',
 '/home/hatsunami/my-first-blog/myvenv/lib/python3.4',
 '/home/hatsunami/my-first-blog/myvenv/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/hatsunami/my-first-blog/myvenv/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/hatsunami/my-first-blog/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
 '/home/hatsunami/my-first-blog']

Server time:    Tue, 22 Nov 2016 17:33:43 +0300

raceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/home/hatsunami/my-first-blog/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner

            response = get_response(request) 
▶ Local vars

/home/hatsunami/my-first-blog/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _legacy_get_response

            response = middleware_method(request) 
▶ Local vars

/home/hatsunami/my-first-blog/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py in process_request

        host = request.get_host() 
▶ Local vars

/home/hatsunami/my-first-blog/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/http/request.py in get_host

            raise DisallowedHost(msg) 
▶ Local vars
```

Что делать подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну в тексте ошибки прямым текстом написано что делать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ('hatsunami.pythonanywhere.com', )
```